# jQuery BlockUI Plugin - IE mouse wait cursor fix for current 01-2011 version?

Tags: jquery, blockui

In IE, BlockUI unblockUI doesn't change the wait cursor back to default.  The cursor changes back to default the instant it moves a pixel after the unblock though (as if the cursor graphic was changed but the cursor doesn't refresh until it moves a pixel):

This [2009 thread had a fix](http://old.nabble.com/-blockUI--IE%3a-Cursor-still-displays-hourglass-symbol-after-unblocking-td25593484s27240.html), but I'm not smart enough to figure out how to modify/apply it to the newest 01-2011 version of BlockUI.  Would an know how to modify the newest version of the plugin or another good work around for this IE problem? I haven't found a working

Fix (doesn't work on 01-2011 version - code modified in this area)

```
Add 
els[1].style.cursor = 'default'; 
After 
var els = full ? $('body').children().filter('.blockUI') : $ 
('.blockUI', el);
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

I scrolled through your provided link ([2009 thread](http://old.nabble.com/-blockUI--IE%3a-Cursor-still-displays-hourglass-symbol-after-unblocking-td25593484s27240.html)) and tried out [this](http://old.nabble.com/Re%3A-IE%3A-Cursor-still-displays-hourglass-symbol-after-unblocking-p25644663s27240.html) suggested fix in that thread where I thought it might work:

Add this line:
   `els[1].style.cursor = 'default';`
*after* line number 389:
   `els = $('body').children().filter('.blockUI').add('body > .blockUI');`

It seems to work for me!  Please let me know if this solves your issues, too!

**Edit**: This is for version 2.36; actually, you probably want to add
   `els[1].style.cursor = 'default';`
*after* line number 392 after this 'if-else' block:
   `var els;`
   `if (full) // crazy selector to handle odd field errors in ie6/7`
      `els = $('body').children().filter('.blockUI').add('body > .blockUI');`
   `else`
      `els = $('.blockUI', el);`

**Edit #2**: In version 2.37, you would:

Add this line:
   `els[1].style.cursor = 'default';`
*after* line number **391** after this 'if-else' block:
   `var els;`
   `if (full) // crazy selector to handle odd field errors in ie6/7`
      `els = $('body').children().filter('.blockUI').add('body > .blockUI');`
   `else`
      `els = $('.blockUI', el);`

Comment: That worked for me - Thanks!  I am using v2.39 of the plugin and had to insert the new code at line 401.

Answer (score 4):

More simply you can add a parameter in blockUI:

```
 $.blockUI({message:'Waiting...',css:{cursor:'default'}});
```

However, you should also put

```
 $('body').css('cursor', 'auto');
```

in the page where you call $.unblockUI().

Answer (score 3):

I used a such approach:

```
$.blockUI({ message: null, overlayCSS: { cursor: "default" } });
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by overriding the global onUnblock of $.blockUI.defaults.
That way I don't have to make any changes to actual source of blockUI source.

```
function restoreCursorOnUnblock(element, options)  {
     var els;
    if (full) { // crazy selector to handle odd field errors in ie6/7
        els = $('body').children().filter('.blockUI').add('body > .blockUI');
    } else {
        els = $('.blockUI', el);
    }
     // restore the default cursor
    els.each(function(i,o) {
         $(o).css('cursor', 'default');
    });
}

function addBlockUiToAjaxStart() {
    $.blockUI.defaults.onUnblock = restoreCursorOnUnblock;
    $('body').ajaxStart(function(event,request, settings){
         $.blockUI({message:''});
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I extended the function reset:

```
// move blocking element back into the DOM where it started
function reset(els, data, opts, el) {
    els.each(function (i, o) {
        // remove via DOM calls so we don't lose event handlers
        $(o).css('cursor', 'default');
        if (this.parentNode)
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
    ...
```

The line

```
$(o).css('cursor', 'default');
```

resets the cursor before the layer gets removed.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to restore the cursor in the remove() function, since the else block calling reset() was skipped in my application. I've posted my working answer for blockUI version 2.3.7

Answer (score 1):

I modified the remove() function in version 2.3.7 of the javascript file as follows:

```
// remove the block
function remove(el, opts) {
    var full = (el == window);
    var $el = $(el);
    var data = $el.data('blockUI.history');
    var to = $el.data('blockUI.timeout');
    if (to) {
        clearTimeout(to);
        $el.removeData('blockUI.timeout');
    }
    opts = $.extend({}, $.blockUI.defaults, opts || {});
    bind(0, el, opts); // unbind events

    var els;
    if (full) // crazy selector to handle odd field errors in ie6/7
        els = $('body').children().filter('.blockUI').add('body > .blockUI');
    else
        els = $('.blockUI', el);

    if (full)
        pageBlock = pageBlockEls = null;

    if (opts.fadeOut) {
        els.fadeOut(opts.fadeOut);
        setTimeout(function() { reset(els,data,opts,el); }, opts.fadeOut);
    }
    else
        reset(els, data, opts, el);

   // restore the default cursor
   els.each(function(i,o) {
        $(o).css('cursor', 'default');
   });
};
```

This is the code I added to the end of the function:

```
// restore the default cursor
els.each(function(i,o) {
     $(o).css('cursor', 'default');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but I just commented out the cursor 'wait' styles in the script as a workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

a suggestion: if wait cursor not important for you, then go to jquery.blockUI.js file and in 
$.blockUI.defaults part, change all cursor(s) value from 'wait' to 'default'

good luck